# couldnt connect to database through Hibernate...too frustating

Tags: java, hibernate

Product.java

```
public class Product {
    private int productId;
    private String proName;
    private double price;

    public void setProductId(int productId)
    {
        this.productId = productId;
    }
    public int getProductId()
    {
        return productId;
    }

    public void setProName(String proName)
    {
        this.proName = proName;
    }
    public String getProName()
    {
        return proName;
    }

    public void setPrice(double price)
    {
        this.price = price;
    }
    public double getPrice()
    {
        return price;
    }
}
```

Product.hbm.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="Product" table="PRODUCTS">

<id name="productId" column="pid"  >
<generator class="assigned" />
</id>

<property name="proName" column="pname" />
<property name="price"/>

</class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>

<!-- Related to the connection START -->
<property name="connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver
</property>
<property name="connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/hibernatedb</property>
<property name="connection.username">postgres</property>
<property name="connection.password">paris</property>
<!-- Related to the connection END -->

<!-- Related to hibernate properties START -->
<property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</property>
<property name="show_sql">true</property>
<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
<!-- Related to hibernate properties END -->

<!-- Related to mapping START -->
<mapping resource="product.hbm.xml" />
<!-- Related to the mapping END -->

</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

ClientForSave.java

```
import org.hibernate.*;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;
import org.hibernate.cfg.*;


public class ClientForSave { 


    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        Configuration cfg = new Configuration();
        cfg.configure(); 
        StandardServiceRegistryBuilder builder=new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(cfg.getProperties());
        SessionFactory factory=cfg.buildSessionFactory(builder.build());
        Session session = factory.openSession();
        Product p=new Product();

        p.setProductId(101);
        p.setProName("iPhone");
        p.setPrice(25000);

        Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(p);
        System.out.println("Object saved successfully.....!!");
        tx.commit();
        session.close();
        factory.close();
    }

}
```

Output at Console is error>>>

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/annotations/common/reflection/MetadataProvider
    at ClientForSave.main(ClientForSave.java:12)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.MetadataProvider
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 1 more
```

P Lease solve this .since 10 days i am trying to code hibernate sample application like this every time it shows me error..i am just a beginner .i request u guys please solve this and explain me in easy way ..thank u for all suggestions

Comment: How do you run your application ?

Answer (score 3):

The exception is actually telling you what the problem is:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/annotations/common/reflection/MetadataProvider
```

At run time, it can't find the class org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.MetadataProvider. You need to provide the jar that has this class in your application's classpath. I don't know what your setup is like, but from the same source where you got your hibernate-core-4.3.1.Final.jar, you should be able to get a hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.4.Final.jar (assuming you're using the latest versions). Retrieve it, put it into your classpath, and the exception should go away.